# Change ProgressBar drawable with style android:progressBarStyleHorizontal

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I need to change the ProgressBar color which is inside a library and I don't have access to it, because it's private

Checking the code, it uses style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"

Is the any way to override the drawable that is used inside that style?

Comment: `which is inside a library` which library ?

Comment: The ProgressBar I need to change